In `git remote`, what is the correct form of SSH URL to a Windows Server directory path?
I'm a novice in Git and SSH.
I usually develop on a local Windows Dev machine and test on a remote Windows Server machine. To make my workflow easier, I try to push the local git repo directly to the remote Windows server using SSH, instead of coping manually.
But it seems to always fail with the error message fatal: ''/c:/Users/User/PSComputerManagementZp.git'' does not appear to be a git repository as:
git push win_test
# user@localhost's password: 
# fatal: ''/c:/Users/User/PSComputerManagementZp.git'' does not appear to be a git repository
# fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

# Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

My git remote is as:
git remote -v
# ubuntu_test     ssh://user@localhost:2201/home/user/PSComputerManagementZp.git (fetch)
# ubuntu_test     ssh://user@localhost:2201/home/user/PSComputerManagementZp.git (push)
# win_test        ssh://user@localhost:2202/c:/Users/User/PSComputerManagementZp.git (fetch)
# win_test        ssh://user@localhost:2202/c:/Users/User/PSComputerManagementZp.git (push)

My debugging steps

First, I eliminate the potential problem of SSH connection. The password type-in procedure demonstrates that the SSH connection works correctly. To further prove that the SSH connection is OK, I do:
ssh -p 2202 user@localhost
# user@localhost's password: 
# Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.4602]
# (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

# user@xxxxxx C:\Users\User>
exit
# Connection to localhost closed.


Then, I make sure the remote repo exits and is an initialized git repo:
ssh -p 2202 user@localhost
# user@localhost's password: 
pwsh
# PS C:\Users\User\PSComputerManagementZp.git>
git init --bare
# Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/Users/User/PSComputerManagementZp.git/



However, after these 2 steps, when git push win_test, the error fatal: ''/c:/Users/User/PSComputerManagementZp.git'' does not appear to be a git repository remains.
Mimic to a remote Ubuntu Server
I've mimicked the same procedure but changed the remote Windows Server to a remote Ubuntu Server, and everything worked without any error:
git remote add ubuntu_test ssh://user@localhost:2201/home/user/PSComputerManagementZp.git
git push ubuntu_test
# user@localhost's password: 
# Everything up-to-date

My supposition and further tests
So, I suppose it's the problem with the SSH URL. The following are several URL forms I've tried with corresponding key error messages:

ssh://user@localhost:2202/c:/Users/...，

but fatal: ''/c:/Users/...'' does not appear to be a git repository


ssh://user@localhost:2202:c:/Users/...,

but ssh: Could not resolve hostname localhost:2202:c:: Name or service not known


ssh://user@localhost:2202/c/Users/...,

but fatal: ''/c/Users/...'' does not appear to be a git repository


ssh://user@localhost:2202/c/Users/...,

but fatal: ''/c$/Users/...'' does not appear to be a git repository


without the protocol user@localhost:2202/c:/Users/xxx

but ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused



My problem
I've tried the methods in the following posts, but they did not work:

Windows, Git and the SSH url/path of a bare repository
git remote server path error
Git remote ssh url

My OpenSSH version: OpenSSH_for_Windows_9.5p1, LibreSSL 3.8.2
So, how to deal with the above problem, fatal: ''/c:/Users/...'' does not appear to be a git repository, when setting git remote like ssh://user@localhost:2202/c:/Users/...?
Or, when pushing to a remote Windows Server directory path via SSH protocol, what is the correct form of SSH URL in git remote?
Thanks in advance.

If your git push ubuntu_test work?

@LajosArpad Yes, I mimic the same procedure but only change the remote Windows Server to a remote Ubuntu Server. It works when pushing to the Ubuntu Server.

Then your path is most probably wrong for Windows. Have you tried /c/Users/User/PSComputerManagementZp.git? (without the colon)

@LajosArpad, Yes, I've tried ssh://user@localhost:2202/c/Users/..., but the error remains as fatal: ''/c/Users/...'' does not appear to be a git repository

This question is similar to: How do I git clone from a Windows machine over ssh?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@phd Thanks. The following is your suggested tests:

ssh -p 2202 user@localhost dir / return Invalid switch - "".
ssh -p 2202 user@localhost dir /c/ return Invalid switch - "".
ssh -p 2202 user@localhost dir /c:/ return Parameter format not correct - "c:".
Only ssh -p 2202 user@localhost dir c:  return the correct response.


@phd  Thanks. Here is the following tests: 5. ssh -p2202 user@localhost dir \\c: returns "\\c:" is not a recognized device. The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
6. ssh -p2202 user@localhost dir \\c:\\Users\\User\\PSComputerManagementZp.git returns The specified path is invalid., 7. ssh -p2202 user@localhost dir c:\Users\\User\\PSComputerManagementZp.git returns correct response as Volume in drive C is Windows ...Volume Serial Number is 4ADC-2BFC ... Directory of c:\Users\User\PSComputerManagementZp.git ...

Ok got it. Double apostrophes in the error message "fatal: ''/c:/Users/...''" means that Git passes parameters in single apostrophes (') and the remote shell (cmd or powershell) doesn't understand it, they require double quotes ("). I found 2 ways to fix that. 1st: change the default shell for ssh at the servers to bash: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68866188/7976758 and restart sshd service. That works for me but I doubt you'd want to do it permanently. To be continued…

Continue… Then the 2nd approach: create shell scripts at the server side that pass unquoted  parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2323826/7976758  and configure local repo to use these remote scripts. I tested and that also works for me. Unfortunately the configuration need to be done in ever repository. The URL should be ssh://user@localhost:2202/c/Users/User/PSComputerManagementZp.git

@phd Thank you. I've tried your first approach and found both URLs .../c:/... and .../c/... worked. I've not tried your second approach but I guess it may also work.  I think they are all expedients but may not be the final solution. Now I'm seeking other ways to share files between local and remote, and trying to use PowerShell sessions, hoping to circumvent sharing code over git directly.

Your openssh seems to be coming from https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH, although the code is coming from https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable.
Since its origin is from BSD/unix, there need to be some translation layer to interact with the windows file system. In practice that means cygwin/msys2 in some form. In a plain/traditional Cygwin installation window drives can be accessed like "c:/windows" or "/cygdrive/c/windows". In the Git for windows environment however, the cygdrive prefix is remove and the access pattern is "c:/windows" or "/c/windows".
Looking into the openssh source code I find
#define CYGWIN_PATH_PREFIX "/cygdrive/"

so I am quite sure your win_test remote should be ssh://user@localhost:2202/cygdrive/c/Users/User/PSComputerManagementZp.git.

That's not how it works – for one, the Win32-OpenSSH build is not using a translation layer, it's a native Win32 build (done by Microsoft), but more importantly, when you run programs via SSH, their file access does not go through OpenSSH. Only file access through SFTP would be handled by the OpenSSH service, but Git doesn't use that – it runs its own protocol server (git-upload-pack or git-receive-pack) through SSH, therefore only Git's own translation layer (if any) applies.
